# Как отправить данные с формы не нарушая работу других обработчиков?

Tags: jquery, ajax, form

С `e.preventDefault` данные из формы  через ajax безпроблем отправляются и обрабатываются на сервере, но форма  не переходи по actiony, без `e.preventDefault` страница переходит по `actionу`, мой нужный ajax запрос вроде проскакивает но не обрабатывается.

Comment: Данные отправляются и обрабатываются != форма не сабмитится. Три раза читал вопрос, так и не смог понять что происходит.

Comment: не понятно что нужно перейти по action или отправить данные с помощью ajax без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Нужно отправить по ajax'у  и затем перейти по action'у

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы `ajax` выполнился до отправки формы можно добавить свойство `async: false` т.е. синхронный запрос.